# Как исправить ошибку подключения к sql в visial studio?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core-mvc

Делаю подключение к базе данных в visual studio проекте asp.net core web app. При подключении через json вылетает ошибка

```
Login failed for user 'diplom'.
```

в самом sql создавала нового пользователя с ником, логином и паролем "diplom", давала ему права администратора.
пробовала делать так:
1 Open your SQL Server Management Studio.
2 Right click on the database server and go to properties.
3 Choose the security option and check "SQL Server and Windows authentication mode".
4 Enable TCP/IP connection in SQL Configuration Manager.
5 Restart your SQL server.
строка подключения в json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=PUZIK;Database=diplom;User Id=diplom;Password=diplom;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
```

пробовала с другим пользователем так https://www.guru99.com/sql-server-create-user.html